gcc recipe failing while running poky build
I have recently started learning and exploring yocto project and while i was running the poky repo in their quick build section of yocto documentation, I am getting this error of:
ERROR : Task (/home/<username>/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_13.2.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'.

I tried re-running but I am getting the error again and again.
I checked the logfiles too but could not get any clear information as to what the problem could be.
Does anyone have any idea!

Please run bitbake gcc-cross -D and provide the relevant debug details.

DEBUG: parsing complete
DEBUG: Target list: ['gcc-cross']
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'gcc-cross'. Close matches:
gcc-cross-x86_64
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message, returning a non-zero exit code.
